# PowerBi DAX equivalent for SUMIFS with current row value as filter

Tags: dax, powerbi

In Excel I could, if I was in a table called 'Sales' that had four columns

**Sales**

```
Month, CustomerId, ProductId, TotalQuantity
Jan,1, CAR,
Feb,1, CAR,
```

I could add a formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Sales[Quantity],Sales[CustomerId],[@[CustomerId]])
```

That would go to the Sales table and sum the CustomerID column filtered by the CustomerID of the current row where the formula has been entered.

I am attempted to replicate this in a PowerBI Calculated Row but I can't get the @ working for a row reference. It comes across like

```
TotalQuantity = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Quantity]),Sales[CustomerId] = Sales[CustomerId]))
```

Any idea how to get the equivalent `@` working?

Comment: This is tagged `powerquery` but the query language isn't M. Do you want to expand your question or change the tags?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your example - all your references are to a single "Sales" table? Where is the Quantity column?

Comment: @CarlWalsh I think I was confused as I had come from the Query Editor in PowerBI (which is also used in PowerQuery so samesame) but was using the AddColumn in Reports which then jumps out of M over to DAX. Correct me if I am wrong on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key function you are missing is EARLIER.  That is not surprising because it has a misleading name - it really means "Current Row". You also need a FILTER function in the Filter parameter of CALCULATE, to reset the filter context to the entire table.

So your New Column function might look like this:

`TotalQuantity = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Quantity]), FILTER(Sales, Sales[CustomerId] = EARLIER (Sales[CustomerId])))`

Here's a neat example, from the most accessible source site for DAX formulas:

http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/07/writing-a-subtotal-calc-column-aka-the-simplest-use-of-the-earlier-function/

And FWIW here is the official doco on EARLIER:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634551.aspx

Comment: Awesome. I was actually about to comment about using FILTER as you edited your answer. Which I picked up from the PowerPivotPro link. TotalQuantity = CALCULATE(SUM([Quantity]),FILTER(Sales,Sales[CustomerId]=EARLIER(Sales[CustomerI‌​d]))) worked! Thank you!

Comment: And yes sorry, I should have had the `CustomerId` column named as `Quantity` but was rushing. I won't change anything as it will mean the answers need to be edited. The solution still works. Thanks again.

Comment: ALLEXCEPT() is cleaner than FILTER() here:    CALCULATE( <expression>, ALLEXCEPT( 'Sales', 'Sales'[CustomerId] ) ) and performs better in a large table.